# How to open a video stream in an application from HTML

Tags: html, media-player

I'm working on a media-streaming software, and I already made apps for multiple platforms, but I'm now trying to port it to the web.

I know that I could transcode content into an `mp4` or `webm` formats that browser supports, but I'd rather move the processing to client-side.

I can "open" a stream, where it asks me to open or save the file, but if I select "open", it downloads it fully and then opens in the media player of choice. The server does support content streaming, so it looks like a waste of having to download it fully to open it.

Is there a way I could open a video stream in a media player (vlc, mpv.io, mpc-hc, ...) without needing manual user intervention (copy-pasting the streaming URL into the player)?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
     <param name="vid" value="http://server.example.com/video1.mpeg"/>
     <embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" name="video"
     autoplay="no" loop="no" width="400" height="320"
     target="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_1280_10MG.mp4" />
</object>
```

Comment: I mentioned above that I'd like to do it without "manual user intervention", which had your answer included in there. I don't think this is a good and user friendly solution, that's why I'm looking for a more "automated" solution.

Comment: How and what does this do? Does this embed VLC into the website? If so, it's not what I want, although it would be a nice solution if it didn't require VLC.

Comment: your code requires NPAPI (npapi-vlc), which was removed from both Firefox and Chrome.